# Вывод данных из поля через ORM Doctrine 1.4

Tags: массивы, orm, запрос, doctrine

Это функция в модели:

```
public function getSocr() {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('socr')
            ->from('KladrStreet')
            ->fetchArray();
    print_r($q);
    exit; }
```

При выводе массива `$q` выходит следующее:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [socr] => ул
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [socr] => ул
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [socr] => ул
```

Как мне построить запрос таким образом, чтобы выборка игнорировала повторяющиеся значения поля `socr`? Нет желания какой-либо парсер придумывать.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
public function getSocr() {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('`DISTINCT` socr')
            ->from('KladrStreet')
            ->fetchArray();
    print_r($q);
    exit; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему так:

```
 $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('socr')
                ->from('KladrStreet')
                ->groupBy('socr')
                ->fetchArray();
```